# Regex doesn't return all img tags - Python

Tags: python, regex, html-parsing

I have a python script that downloads the html and the images shown in the html so I can open the file locally.

It works fine, the only problem is, there is a certain div in which the images don't get downloaded/found by the regex. I have no idea why tho. It's not a huge problem, but I'd like to know the reason.

This is the important part of the script:

```
url = "http://www.somedomain.com"
urlContent = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
#Write originalHtml to file
f = open("originalHtml",'w')
f.write(urlContent)
f.close()
# HTML image tag: some_text
imgUrls = re.findall('img .*?src="(.*?)"', urlContent)
```

After that I loop over the links, one by one, downloading the images and replacing the links in the html so the "src" points to the local path where I downloaded it. The script takes care of relative links and direct links.

However, part of the images never gets downloaded. 
This is html that doesn't get picked up :

```
<img src="/images/news/den-mcx80001.jpg" style="width:60px;height:36px;margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:17px; margin-right:17px;float:left; ">
```

This however does get picked up:

```
<img class="productimg" style="width:72px;height:74px;margin-top:15px; margin-bottom:15px; margin-left:3px; margin-right:28px " src="/images/01_prdarticledocs/ImagesSmall/jpr/jpr-prx718xlf.jpg" alt="jpr-prx718xlf">
```

I'm not an expert in regexes, far from it, but it does seem that it should pick up both, no?

Comment: Use beautifulsoup library

Comment: This is one of many reasons to not parse HTML with regex.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4473405

Comment: Right, that one. Sad thing is, I knew that post.. Well then, starting over again.

Comment: Mini snippet that shows your code should work https://repl.it/BixJ/0

Comment: Logic says it should work, but in the complete file it doesn't. I'm trying with beautifulsoup now, but some beautifulsoup solutions even work with regexes..

Comment: Side note, `.*?` is the same as `.*` which is also the same as `.+?`

In all cases, just use `.*` :)

Comment: Try Using `"<img.+?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].*?>"` to match. There may be some stuff between `<img` and `src=`,  `.+?` can match that part.

Comment: Switched to BeautifulSoup as suggested, see solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with BeautifulSoup, as the comments suggested.
Code snippet for anyone looking for a script to download HTML with the Images, save them and relink the images in the html to local relative links.

```
import urllib2
import re
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from os.path import basename
from urlparse import urlsplit

#get content of a url and save (not necessary) the originalhtml
url = "http://www.someDomain.com"
urlContent = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
page = BeautifulSoup(urlContent)
f = open("originalHtml",'w')
f.write(urlContent)
f.close()
#Find all images in the file, put them in imgUrls 
imgUrls = page.findAll('img')
imagesDict = {}

# download all images
for image in imgUrls:
    try:
        #get src tag and download file, save link and local link in dict
        imgUrl = image['src']
        imgData = urllib2.urlopen(imgUrl).read()
        fileName = basename(urlsplit(imgUrl)[2])
        location = "images/" + fileName;
        imagesDict[location] = imgUrl
        print "loc=" + location
        output = open(location,'wb')
        output.write(imgData)
        output.close()
    except:
        #not so clean solution to catch hard-linked images ('http://somedomain.com/img/image.jpg
        try:
            imgData = urllib2.urlopen(url + imgUrl).read()
            fileName =  basename(urlsplit(imgUrl)[2])
            location = "images/" + fileName
            imagesDict[location] = imgUrl
            print "loc=" + location
            output = open(location,'wb')
            output.write(imgData)
            output.close()
        except:
            print "Double ERROR"
        print "Error" + imgUrl
        pass

#Replace the old links to new local links
for dictKey in imagesDict:
    urlContent = re.sub(imagesDict[dictKey], dictKey, urlContent)


#save HTML
f = open("imagesReplaced.html", 'w')
f.write(urlContent)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

**You should not use regex to parse html.**

It's really hard to debug these failures. I can't see any reason why the image tags you post should not be matched by the regex. But here are a few examples where this regex pattern will fail.

```
urlContent = """
single quotes     <img src='/image/one.jpg' /> 
unexpected space  <img src ="/image/two.jpg" /> 
not an img tag    <script src="/some/javascript.js"> 
"""
>>> re.findall('img .*?src="(.*?)"', urlContent)

['/some/javascript.js']
```

Using a html/xml parser as the other answer suggests is the only sane way to solve your problem.

PS: This has already been linked in the comments, but I guess it's mandatory to include this answer every time the topic is discussed: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)